# How to fix opencv visual studio based application run error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I developed an application under visual studio 2010 based on OpenCV 2.4.11
the build is successful but the launch finished by the current error logs that i don't understand

[image: Logs error]

Please help me what should i do to fix this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any error message there, just missing pdb files (and that's not a problem per se). Post the code and the actual error.

Comment: i searched in all my project i have pdb files with the opencv but i dont know where to put them.